# Buttons are not working after adding as subviews to background image

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, subviews

I have a working login Viewcontroller but when I added a background image the functionality of buttons are not working, there is no syntax error. When I added as just background image every button works fine but when I added buttons as subviews the buttons are not working.

Here is my VC:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Foundation

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var imageView = UIImageView()

    @IBOutlet weak var signupButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var directButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var emailText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passText: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
    @IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {

            let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext
            var isMatched = false
            let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
            request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
            do {
                let results = try! context.fetch(request)
                if(results.count > 0){
                    for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]
                    {
                        if  emailText.text == result.value(forKey: "username") as? String && passText.text == result.value(forKey: "password") as? String {
                            print(emailText.text!, passText.text!)
                           // usernameGlobal = self.emailText.text!
                            let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle : nil)
                            let desController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddViewController") as! AddViewController
                            let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)
                            revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)
                            isMatched = true
                            break
                        }
                    }

                    if !isMatched {
                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Incorrect username or password", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
    }



    @IBAction func directAction(_ sender: Any) {


        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle : nil)
        let desController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddViewController") as! AddViewController
        let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)
        revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)


    }



    @IBAction func signupSegue(_ sender: Any) {

        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle : nil)
        let desController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignupViewController") as! SignupViewController
        let newFrontViewController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController:desController)
        revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "dsplash")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
         imageView.alpha = 0.5

        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        self.imageView.addSubview(emailText)
        self.imageView.addSubview(passText)
        self.imageView.addSubview(loginButton)
        self.imageView.addSubview(signupButton)
        self.imageView.addSubview(directButton)

        loginButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: try setting `imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't add buttons as subviews of the `imageView`, they are laid out by the storyboards. Rather just change this line of code:

```
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

to this:

```
self.view.insertSubview(imageView, at: 0)
```

And then remove the lines of code where you put buttons as subviews of the `imageView`.

That will put the image below the buttons, so it will look as you want it, and the buttons will keep working.

Or even better, add that `imageView` through storyboards (I like being consistent). To keep it as a background image, just drag the `imageView` int the View Controller Scene to the top of the subviews, so that it is the first subview of the view - that will make all the rest of the view to appear before it:

[image]

Alternatively if you have a good reason to keep the buttons as `imageView` subviews, set `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true` to make it work with buttons as subviews of the `imageView`.

Answer (score 0):

Image view user interaction enable is no by default. you need to change it. use [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled: Yes] ;